# eclipse failed to load jni shared liberary

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

**Screens shot:** http://prntscr.com/26jl07

**Java version:** http://prntscr.com/26jmz3

Below is my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

I would really appreciate some help. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a 64 bit version of Eclipse using 32 bit Java. This is not possible.

To resolve the problem:

- Install 64 bit Java and restart your 64 bit Eclipse using it.
- Install 32 bit Eclipse and restart using your current 32 bit Java

Comment: You are launching a 64 bit Eclipse with 32 bit Java. Notice in `eclipse.ini` e.g. `-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin`.
Change that to point to 64 bit Java and you'll be all set